Flutter GoRouter.go does not working in the release mode
I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter project involving the oauth2_client package for connecting to a custom Single Sign-On (SSO) server. The application flow is structured as follows:

Splash Screen

Settings Screen: Users input a server URL. Here, I fetch SSO server configuration via an API call and pass it to the oauth2_client package.
OAuth2 Client Login: Upon user initiation, the oauth2_client launches a login page in a webview, where users input their credentials. Upon successful login, the app returns to the settings page with a callback. At this point, I verify the user token and navigate to the home page using the following statement:
AppRouter.router.go(AppRouter.home);


This operation functions correctly.
In the home page, users can navigate to the profile page and subsequently log out. Upon logout, I invoke the logout function and redirect the user to the settings page using:
AppRouter.router.go(AppRouter.settingsPage);

However, the problem arises when attempting to log in again after logging out. Although the login process succeeds, and I can verify the user token, the statement:
AppRouter.router.go(AppRouter.home);

fails to navigate the app to the home screen.
Two noteworthy observations:

If the user closes the app after logging out and reopens it, the login process works seamlessly, navigating to the home page.

This issue occurs exclusively in Android release mode; the debug mode operates without any problems.


I've attempted various navigation methods (go, push, replace, pushReplacement) in the router without success. Additionally, I've tried clearing all screens after logout before navigating to the settings screen, but this approach also failed to resolve the issue.
What could be causing this behavior? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

In my case, I updated:
MaterialApp.router(

   //...

   routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
   routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
   backButtonDispatcher: router.backButtonDispatcher,
)

to
MaterialApp.router(
        
  //...
    
  routerConfig: router,
)

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77530245/22282531
